# Calling methods in two different classes: Calling eachothers' methods

Tags: java, object, methods

I have 2 different classes that are both calling methods from each other. For some reason, when I added an object in the class that had already had an object called from the other class, it gives me a stack overflow error. Here's what I'm dealing with:

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {
    ClassB objA = new ClassB();
}
```

ClassB:

```
public class ClassB {
  ClassA objB = new ClassA();
}
```

When trying to run I am given the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at package.ClassB.<init>(ClassB.java)
    at package.ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:26)
    at package.ClassB.<init>(ClassB.java:17)
```

Lines 26 and 17 are where the objects created (like my examples above) are. The bottom 2 lines of my error example repeat at least 50 times.

Comment: well, duh. Each time you create an instance of classA, you create a new instance of classB, which in turn creates a new instance of classA, which creates a new instance of classB, which creates a new instance of classA, ...

Comment: Be advised: only use bidirectional relations if you have to, as they are hard to maintain. You need to enforce the bidirectional relation yourself.

Answer (score 4):

When you create an instance of `ClassA`, an instance of `ClassB` is created.

When you create an instance of `ClassB`, an instance of `ClassA` is created.

Hence when creating an instance of either of these classes, you start a chain of infinite instance creations, leading to `StackOverflowError`.

If you need `ClassA` to hold a reference to an instance of `ClassB` and vice versa, I suggest that instead of one class internally creating an instance of the other, you pass a reference to a created instance in a setter method:

```
public class ClassA {

    ClassB objA;


    public setB (ClassB b) {
        objA = b;
    }
}

public class ClassB {

    ClassA objB;

    public setA (ClassA a) {
        objB = a;
    }

}
```

And then you create the instances this way:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
```

Comment: So how do I fix it? These classes have to call each others' methods.

Comment: @Confused just added that to answer

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can't mix up classA and ClassA

Comment: @Stultuske thanks. I didn't even notice the different case.

Comment: thank you! In which class do I put the bottom part? The stuff you included after "And then:"

Comment: @Confused In the part of your code that creates the ClassA and ClassB instances. Where do you create the original ClassA or ClassB instance?